# show() View Controller doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I try to authenticate the user of my app if they are not. I first read the value saved in UserDefaults to know if they are logged in, and if not, I want to show the ViewController to allow them to log in.

But anyway, the LogInViewController won't show, this is my code :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userIsConnected")){
         let LogVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInViewController") as! LogInViewController
         show(LogVC, sender: self)
    }
}
```

I also tried without the 'if' condition, and it doesn't work anymore

**EDIT :**
I also tried presentVC() and I had the error "Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy"

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you get any warning/error  in console ?

Comment: Is `show(LogVC, sender: self)` even called? Do you have a message in Console saying that view is not present in window hierarchy?

Comment: I have no errors in console with show(), I also tried presentVC() and I had the error "Attempt to present <DroneSpot.LogInViewController: 0x10792c3c0> on <DroneSpot.MainViewController: 0x10323d470> whose view is not in the window hierarchy"

Comment: Do that in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()`, the `"Attempt to present YyY on ZzZ whose view is not in the window hierarchy"` is explicit, you can look for it.

Comment: I already tried in `viewDidAppear()`but it doesn't work, I have the same error

Comment: Have you tried using a segue?

Comment: I didn't know I could use a segue with a `if() {}` condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to login in the `MainViewController`. You should avoid when possible managing your login in a view controller. The login is more effective if managed in your `AppDelegate`.

Add this code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate.swift

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userIsConnected") {
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
      let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInViewController")
      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
      window?.rootViewController?.present(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil
}
```

Make sure you can access `UserDefaults`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.